# How to set database service objective when publishing it using sqlpackage.exe

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I am using sqlpackage.exe, available with the SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (preview) to publish a database to SQL Azure (from a bacpac file previously exported from a local database server).

The problem is that this database is created with the S0 service objective (which I suppose is the default).

I would like to be able to set the service objective of the target in the import command with sqlpackage.exe.

I have searched for an answer and I cannot find anything in the sqlpackage.exe documentation available here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx

I see the management studio UI allows to set the service objetive and I understand that it uses sqlpackage.exe underneath.

Anyone has an idea on how to get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the documentation is out-of-date, and I've reached out to the internal team to update it. But if you look for help on import, you should see the parameter to be supplied for Service Level Objective (SLO).

> SqlPackage.exe /a:Import /?

/p:DatabaseEdition=({Web|Business|Basic|Standard|Premium|Default} 'Default')
     Defines the edition of a Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

/p:DatabaseServiceObjective=(STRING)
     Defines the performance level of a Microsoft Azure SQL Database such as
     "P0" or "S1".

However, if you want to change the SLO after the database has been created there is no sqlpackage.exe support. You'll have to do it via TSQL, Powershell, API or Portal.

Best,
Saloni

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand that you could help on a specific action.